# Locally overriding System Colours

Tags: wpf

I am trying to change the highlight brush color of a list box item by overriding SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey. But unfortunately it doesn't work with the following code.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstItems"  >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

My code is taken from this [WPFTutorial.net page](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ListBoxSelectionBackground.html) where you can see the selected item is highlighted with red color.

But I still get the default behavior as shown in the following screenshot.
[image]

I am developing using .NET 4.5

What am I missing here?

Comment: Works for me. What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Clemens Edited the question to elaborate

Comment: @Fadi, are you using Windows 8?

Comment: @Sheridan Yes. I am using Windows 8. Referring to the linked post,  I understand what caused the trouble. Thank you